# What are Win64 threads in MSVS debugger?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, visual-studio

for some time I have been noticing entries named "Win64 Thread" in the combo box for switching threads in Visual Studio (2010). What are they? I do multithread but I don't think I am the one who creates these ones. Process Explorer shows in my opinion correct number of thread handles which is the number of all entries in that combo box minus those named Win64 Thread. What is going on?

Comment: Good question.  I would hazard a *guess* that you are running a 32-bit application and that these are 64-bit threads used by the WOW64 system.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Unfortunatelly not. In this case the application was x64. If I compile project for x86 the entry name is Win32 Thread. I assume you suspect that the debugger could create more handles to my threads. That's so a good guess. So I found those handles in Process Explorer after all. In devenv.exe (they have different stacks so they are probably not related to my threads). No idea why do they put these in there as an option since you can't really use it in any way, but pfffft.. I don't care <- not my handles. If you want you can state this as an answer and I accept it :)

Comment: Nah, you did the work - go ahead and answer it yourself.

Comment: Thread *handles* are not showing up in the threads window. Only actual threads are.

Comment: @usr You are right, my bad. The number I was talking about is actually the thread ID, but the problem and explanation remain the same. I didn't create those threads and ProcExplorer shows only those I actually created. (+thread IDs as part of the name of the object, which is why I mixed it up)